# How to test controllers with nested routes using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

I have 2 controllers that I created using scaffold generator of rails. I wanted them to be nested in a folder called "demo" and so ran

```
rails g scaffold demo/flows
rails g scaffold demo/nodes
```

Then I decided to nest nodes inside flows, and changed my routes file like so:

```
namespace :demo do 
  resources :flows do
    resources :nodes
  end
end
```

But this change resulted on the rspec tests for nodes breaking with ActionController::Routing errors.

```
  15) Demo::NodesController DELETE destroy redirects to the demo_nodes list
     Failure/Error: delete :destroy, :id => "1"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:id=>"1", :controller=>"demo/nodes", :action=>"destroy"}
```

The problem is rspec is looking at the wrong route. It's supposed to look for "demo/flows/1/nodes". It also needs a mock model for flow, but I am not sure how to provide that. Here is my sample code from generated rspec file:

```
  def mock_node(stubs={})
    @mock_node ||= mock_model(Demo::Node, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all demo_nodes as @demo_nodes" do
      Demo::Node.stub(:all) { [mock_node] }
      get :index
      assigns(:demo_nodes).should eq([mock_node])
    end
  end
```

Can someone help me understand how I need to provide the flow model?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two different questions going on here, so you may want to split them up since your second question has nothing to do with the title of this post.  I would recommend using FactoryGirl for creating mock models https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Your route error is coming from the fact that your nested routes require id's after each one of them like this:

```
/demo/flows/:flow_id/nodes/:id
```

When you do the delete on the object, you need to pass in the flow ID or else it won't know what route you are talking about.

```
delete :destroy, :id => "1", :flow_id => "1"
```

In the future, the easiest way to check what it expects is to run `rake routes` and compare the output for that route with what you params you are passing in.

```
demo_flow_node  /demo/flows/:flow_id/nodes/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"demo/flows"}
```