# How to test controllers with nested routes using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I create controller with InherritedResource

```
class AppsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :company

  # Devise
  before_filter :login_or_oauth_required
  # CanCan
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

and try to test it with Rspec by this method

```
require "spec_helper"

include Devise::TestHelpers

describe AppsController do
  before(:each) do
    @company_1 = Factory.build(:company)
    application_1 = Factory.create(:application, :company => @company_1)
    application_2 = Factory.create(:application, :company => @company_1)
    application_3  = Factory.create(:application, :company => @company_1)    
    @company_2 = Factory.build(:company)

    @user_1   = Factory.create(:user)
    role_1    = Factory.create(:publisher_role, :company => @company_1) 
    profile_1 = Factory.create(:profile, :company => @company_1, :user => @user_1, :roles => [role_1])
  end

  describe "index action" do
    it "user_1 should have 3 applications from company_1" do
      sign_in @user_1
      params = {"company_id"=>"1"}
      get :index
      assigns[:apps].should have(3).items
    end
  end
end
```

The result is

```
Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"apps"}
```

How to tell Rspec to "Get" in to my nested route

My routes

```
  resources :companies do
    resources :apps do
      resources :shelves do
        resources :publications
      end
    end
  end
```

I try to follow this Question [How to test controllers with nested routes using Rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714732/how-to-test-controllers-with-nested-routes-using-rspec) but it's not work on my case

I use Rails 3.1.1 and rspac 2.7

Comment: fwiw, the Rails Guides discourage nesting resources beyond one level "Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep," (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) referring readers to this [monstrosity](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources). But ya do watcha gotta do.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found solution :-P

What I did was just to change from

```
get :index
```

to

```
get :index, :company_id => @company_1.id
```

Comment: Or in new rspec syntax `get :index, params: { company_id: @company_1.id }`